# Dash: apply 3rd-party or self custom css and js to dash elements

Tags: javascript, python, html, plotly-dash

I am developing a dash application which is a multi-page app. I am using bootstrap theme.

**project structure**

```
- proj
  - app.py
  - pages/
    - index.py
    - demo.py
  - assets/
    - 1_third_party_style.css
    - 2_third_party_script.js
    - 3_custom_script.js
```

In app.py, I have a sidebar containing navitems for home(index) and demo pages and div that loads the contents from home or demo pages whichever user has clicked.

**app.py**

```
// design

server = Flask(__name__)

app = Dash(
    __name__,
    server=server,
    suppress_callback_exceptions=True,
)

def serve_sidebar() -> html.Div:
    return html.Div(
           dbc.Nav([
                     dbc.NavLink("Home", href="/", active="exact"),
                     dbc.NavLink("Demo", href="/demo", active="exact"),
                   ],
                   vertical=True,
                   pills=True,
           ),    
    ) 


def serve_content() -> html.Div:
    return html.Div(id="page-content", style=CONTENT_STYLE)


def serve_layout() -> html.Div:
    return html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Location(id="url", refresh=True),  // set true to refresh the page              
            serve_sidebar(),
            serve_content(),
        ],
        id="div_main",
    )

app.layout = serve_layout

// callback

@callback(
    Output(component_id="page-content", component_property="children"),
    Input(component_id="url", component_property="pathname"),
)
def display_page(pathname: str) -> html.Div:

    if pathname == "/":
        return index.layout
    elif pathname == "/demo":
        return demo.layout
```

**index.py**

```
// design

def serve_layout() -> html.Div:

    return html.Div(
        [
            "Welcome to my Dash app",
        ]
    )


layout = serve_layout()
```

**demo.py**

```
// design

def serve_layout() -> html.Div:

    return html.Div(
        [
            html.Form(
                id="form_demo",
                name="form_demo",
                method="POST",
                action="/baz",    
                children=html.Div(
                    id="div_demo",
                    children="This is Form contents",
                    className="bar", // this is from 3rd party css
                ),
            )
        ]
    )


layout = serve_layout()
```

**custom_script.js**

```
if (window.location.pathname == "/demo") {
    
    alert(window.location.pathname);
    
    if (window.PageTransitionEvent) {

        alert("ok-page-transitioned")
        
        if (window.document.getElementById("#form_demo")) {
               
               alert("ok-form-loaded")
               
               if (window.document.getElementById("#div_demo")) {
               
                     alert("ok-div-demo-loaded")
               
               }        
        
         }

     }
}
```

Once app is launched the default index(home) is loaded and displayed.

My goal is when user click on demo page, I want to attach some 3rd party style class (css) which I have defined in className, 3rd party script(js) and my own custom_script(js) to **div_demo element**. All assets are **local**.

Expected:

- all 4 alerts should pop-up (just for testing purpose, thereby assuring all assets are working(my goal)

**case-1:** (normal flow)

- Action:

  - User is on index page, and now clicks on demo page from sidebar.
- Observed:

  - Not a single alert is displayed
  - but page-contents for demo page is loaded

**case-2:**

- Action:

  - User is on index page, and now clicks on demo page from sidebar.
  - Now clicks on refresh button of the web browser.
- Observed:

  - alert for pathname and page transition is displayed
  - page-contents of demo page is loaded
  - but alert for form and div-demo is not displayed

**case-3:**

- Action:

  - User directly visit url as localhost/demo in the address bar and hits enter.
- Observed:

  - alert for pathname and page transition is displayed
  - page-contents of demo page is loaded
  - but alert for form and div-demo is not displayed

why alert for form and div-demo are not working?
How to apply 3rd-party or self css and js [all local inside assets] to dash elements from different pages.
I searched alot but no luck.